# Performance of Gutenberg block attributes with source selectors vs without

Tags: block-editor

Are there any performance considerations I should take into account between choosing to store block attributes with a source selector or storing them in the comment delimiter?

My assumption is a source selector would be more efficient when it comes to database size and queries, but I don't know how performant the script that extracts the attributes from the markup is versus the script that extracts them from the comments.